# Why adding "variable + 1" doesn't increment its value by one for every loop in a for loop? (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, increment

I'm having a hard time understanding why using a increment operator in a for loop in C++ has a different result than doing 'variable' + 1. The variable in the second case simply isn't remembered after each iteration of the loop:

Take the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a{0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::cout << ++a;
    }
return 0;
}
```

It outputs as expected:
12345

However, if I instead replace ++a with a + 1:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a{0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::cout << a + 1;
    }
return 0;
}
```

I get:
11111

Even if I make the 'a' variable static:

```
static int a{0};
```

It still outputs 11111.

Why doesn't 'a + 1' preserve its value after every loop? What would I need to do if I wanted to preserve its value after every iteration without using ++ (for instance, with another operation like a * 2)?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `std::cout << a + 1` doesn't affect `a` in any way. This is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: For the same reason that `5+6` doesn't morph `5` into `11`.

Comment: `std::cout << a; a += 1;` (or `a *= 2;` or whatever it is that you want to do).

Comment: @GuilhermeMS No, it does not affect a. The `a` is still `0` after doing `a+1`.

Comment: **Stackoverflow is not an introduction to C++**. This is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I still don't quite understand what your end-goal is.  It is obvious why `a + 1` doesn't do anything to `a`, since there is no assignment to `a` going on.

Comment: Interesting.  I get it now @JasonLiam, thanks a lot. With a + 1 'a' was never assigned anything. It got incremented by 1 in the output because the result of that operation was being passed to cout, however a was still 0, that's why when it looped it simply added 0 + 1 again. :D

Comment: Since `a` is an `int`, the expression `a + 1` accesses the value of `a`, and produces a result equivalent to `a + 1`.   It does not change the value of `a` at all.   This is explained in any beginner/introductory text on C++ (and also in any beginner/introductory text on C - the working of the expression `a + 1` is the same in both C and C++, although C does not have `std::cout`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't 'a + 1' preserve its value after every loop?

`a + 1` is an expression that **doesn't assign anything to** `a`. That is `a` is not affected in any way. This means when you do just `a + 1`, the value of `a` is still `0`(the old value).

On the other hand `++a` has the same effect as:

```
  v---------->assignment done here implicitly
a = a+1
```

In the above expression `++a`, the value of is incremented by `1` so that the new value of `a` is now `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`++a` is equivalent to the assignment `a= a + 1` (or `a+= 1`). The expression `a + 1` alone does not modify `a`.

C++ will allow you to write `std::cout << (a= a + 1);`.

Answer (score 0):

`a++` is not the same thing as `a+1` but as `a=a+1`.
What's the difference?

Well:
`a+1` **contains** the value, which is one higher than the value of `a`.
`a=a+1` means that, in top of this, this value gets assigned to the variable `a`, which means something like "**replace `a`** by its value plus one".

This gives following possibilities (I also show the difference between `a++` and `++a`):

```
int a=3;
cout<<a+1; // output : 4. Value of 'a' equals 3.
cout<<a+1; // output : 4. Value of 'a' equals 3.
cout<<a+1; // output : 4. Value of 'a' equals 3.

int a=3;
cout<<a++;  // output : 3. Value of 'a' becomes 4 after having shown it on screen.
cout<<a++;  // output : 4. Value of 'a' becomes 5 after having shown it on screen.
cout<<a++;  // output : 5. Value of 'a' becomes 6 after having shown it on screen.

int a=3;
cout<<++a;  // output : 4. Value of 'a' becomes 4 before showning it on screen.
cout<<++a;  // output : 5. Value of 'a' becomes 5 before showning it on screen.
cout<<++a;  // output : 6. Value of 'a' becomes 6 before showning it on screen.
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the built-in arithmetic operators like `+` and `*` *evaluate* their operands, perform the respective operation with the thusly obtained values, and create a temporary object that contains the result.

The operands, one of which is your `a`, are only read from, not written to. That is more obvious when you consider that `+` is *commutative*, that is, its operands can be swapped without affecting the result: `a+1` is by definition the same as `1+a`, and clearly you cannot write anything back to the immediate value `1`.

Generally, as you certainly know, `=` is used in C and C++ to *write* a value to a variable. C, and by means of ancestry also C++, provide shortcuts to write back the result of certain operations to one of their operands: it's the combination of the operator and the assignment `=`, for example `a += 1`. Like all assignments, this one is an *expression* (that is, it has a value) which has the value of the variable after the operation and assignment. Like all other expressions, you can use it as a subexpression, even though that's not very common: `cout << (a += 1);` would achieve the desired effect (the parentheses are necessary because assignment has about the lowest operator precedence). Because incrementing (and decrementing) by one is so very common, C and C++ have a shortcut for the shortcut: `++a` is the same as `a+=1`, so that one would typically write `cout << ++a;` (as a side effect obviating the need for parentheses).